# C#.net or Node.Js in Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, botframework, chatbot

I want to build my first chatbot using **Microsoft Bot Framework**. Now I have 2 options, either to use **C#.net** or **Node.Js**. Please guide me which would be a better option for me as a beginner in chatbot development and also why.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. For me there's no "better" option between the two. I would suggest use the language that you're very comfortable with.

But if you're not familiar with those languages, you could probably check this [link](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/getting-started-with-bots-16759) to get you started with developing in Chat Bots

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14292476)

Comment: Awesome. Will take note of that, thanks a lot!

Comment: @PhilipDomingo
Thanks a lot for the link :)
Also, is there some way I could use Java with Microsoft Bot Framework?

Comment: Yes, though you will be doing it via REST API because, only C# and Node.js has the available SDK for Bot framework right now.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is a decision you need to make it for yourself. Essentially, what you're asking is "which one is better, C# or Node?" which is practically comparing oranges to planets. Since Microsoft Bot Framework SDK is both available on .NET and Node JS, you should be making that decision.